# Migration java8 to java11: import com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem

Tags: java, security, migration, java-11

just started a migration java 8 to 11.
While in java 8, rt.jar and others were easily available, we used

```
import com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem;
```

Using java 11, my IDE (intellij) tells me:

```
Error:(3, 36) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NTSystem
  location: package com.sun.security.auth.module
```

Any idea what I need to change?

Comment: @nullpointer thanks. Any idea how to replace that one? I need to determine whether the app is running on Windows and has Administrator rights?

Comment: com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem has not been removed, it's in the jdk.security.auth module, see: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.security.auth/com/sun/security/auth/module/NTSystem.html

Comment: It is possible that you migrating to modules at the same time as upgrading to JDK 11, in which case maybe your module is missing `requires jdk.security.auth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your module doesn't have `module-info.java` then the class `NTSystem` should be available. Otherwise, you can add `requires jdk.security.auth` to make it available:

```
module <module-name> {
    requires jdk.security.auth;
}
```

Also, remember that IDEA is a smart IDE and you can press Alt+Enter on the error line to see a quick fix for the error. In your case, IDE will propose to add `requires jdk.security.auth`.